# Modify variable into log_format

Tags: nginx, regex

I have simple config:

```
http {
    log_format          main  '"rmethod":"$request_method" "uri":"$uri" "args":"$args";

    access_log          /tmp/nginx_access.log  main;
...
}
```

Problem is that `args` contains sensitive information. Can I hide some query parameters?

For example:

`$args` value is `cmd=list&username=qwe&ext=625&sensitive_info=sfsfsd&cred=Black0ps5762`

After using regex `^(.*)((?:sensitive_info=.*)&)(.*)$` will form a new variable by capture groups: `args = $1$3`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem:

```
map $args $hidden_args {
    default $args;
    '~*^(?<arg0>.*)(sensitive_info=\w*)(?<arg1>.*)$' "${arg0}sensitive_info=***${arg1}";
}

log_format   main  '"rmethod":"$request_method" "uri":"$uri" "args":"$hidden_args";
```